# Adjusting the gain in Pre-Built Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain, diagram, hacking

I have bought a phono-preamp stage from Audio Technica, and the output is quite low. (*Using a MM cartridge*.) I managed to retrieve a data-sheet which shows how the circuit is laid out.
[image: Phono Pre-Amp Circuit]
I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. The setup seems to be a fairly standard non-inverting OP-Amp setup. The Equalization appears to happen in the feeback. I initially thought R28/R18 were responsible for the gain but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm a bit stumped and would love to know if anyone knows if what I'm attempting to do is even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Any EE lesson is of course welcome. I'd love to learn more about how (and why) this works as it does, if that's not asking too much!

Comment: I would have looked at R6/R7 but at 1k0 its already low so at best you might only get another 3dB

Comment: What do you mean 'the output is low'?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with per say, it's just quite a bit lower than the rest of the line level input which leads to possible jump scares and possibly angry neighbors when I forget and switch sources.

Comment: *I initially thought R28/R18 were responsible for the gain but that doesn't seem to be the case.* No those are for biasing, roughly the gain is (R9+R10) / R6. But if you change any of those values then the EQ curve will also change. You would be better off adding an amplifier (without EQ) behind this circuit.

Comment: It isn't quite straightforward thanks to R5(R8), plus the gain setting and EQ are intimately interlinked. Best option is to simulate first, then halve R6/R7 and see the changes. You probably need to double C5,C6, C22,C23 to maintain the LF time constants (correct bass response curve), and you may need to change R5/R8 too.

Comment: I think you may be plugging the output into something that may only have (say) 1 kohm input impedance. Note that these amps have an output impedance of 4.7 kohm thus, you might see a signal reduction (into 1 kohm) of over 13 dB.

Answer (score 2):

**It looks like the answer was indeed R6/R7.** These two resistors with the equalization network of R9 - R12 & C7 - C11 do indeed determine the gain.

As suggested, I simulated the circuit, and the default gain at 1kHz was 35db. Halving R6/R7 have raised the gain to 43db. Instead I chose a 1.3kOhm resistor in parallel via switch, giving about 600 Ohm and yielding an output of ~40db.

I also checked the RIAA equalization in the simulation for all three scenarios, and it's true that the equalization is slightly affected, the low-frequencies which are slightly more attenuated (less amplified) if the gain is increased. For 390 Ohms the deviation at the 20Hz end is about -3db. The equalization of frequencies from 1kHz and up isn't affected for some reason.

I picked 600 Ohm as final value since the deviation at 20Hz is about -1db VS the ideal RIAA-equalization curve and this is probably inaudible, especially since my speakers top out at around 40Hz anyway.

Upon implementing the above discussed changes (with a toggle switch) it seemed to bear the simulation results out.

Comment: It's good practice to accept your own answer so future users can easily recognise this question has been correctly answered.